# How do I generate CSRF tokens in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

newbie. 
I'm using ExpressJS/Node. Here's my config stuff:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express.createServer(),
jade=require('jade');
// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "secretive secret" }));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.csrf());
```

I found csrf.js in Express directories, and see that it should be generated and assigned to req.body._csrf, but I'm not sure how to access it.

Here's the csrf.js code

```
module.exports = function csrf(options) {
var options = options || {}
, value = options.value || defaultValue;

return function(req, res, next){
// generate CSRF token
var token = req.session._csrf || (req.session._csrf = utils.uid(24));

// ignore GET (for now)
if ('GET' == req.method) return next();

// determine value
var val = value(req);

// check
if (val != token) return utils.forbidden(res);

next();
}
};
```

Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dynamic helpers has been removed from Express since 3.x.

The new usage would be `app.use(express.csrf());`, which comes from [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html).

Answer (score 5):

Add the token to dynamic helpers.

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  token: function(req, res) {
    return req.session._csrf;
  }
});
```

Reference it in your jade template.

```
input(type='hidden', value=token)
```

Source:  http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-csrf.html

Answer (score 1):

In **Express 4.x** this middleware is removed. For Express 4.x you can do it as follows

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
app.use(csrf());
```

Ah!! you need to register the `csrf` middleware after your `session` and `cookieParser` middleware.

Inside Route Or Ctrl

```
res.render('someform', { csrf: req.csrfToken() });
```

or You can set a local variable also like so

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.csrf = req.csrfToken();
});
```

Then in view

```
input(type="hidden", name="_csrf", value="#{csrf}")
```

You are done!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to set a secure cookie for your CSRF token that can be read by your frontend (angular for example), you can do this:

```
app.use csrf()

app.use (req, res, next) ->
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(), {secure: true})
next()
```