# Generating _csrf in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, connect, csrf

I'm a newbie. I'm using a browser plugin that hits my node server, and need a csrf token.

What I have isn't generating anything:

```
app.use(express.csrf());
app.dynamicHelpers({
    token: function(req, res) {
    return req.session._csrf;
  }
});
```

...and then I reference token in my jade file

```
input(type="hidden", token=token)
```

I don't understand what should be generating the token--guessing connect. Regardless I don't see a value.

tried 
    console.log(token) as well //undefined

I posed the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707119/how-do-i-generate-csrf-tokens-in-express) and had it working, but now it's not after upgrading to node .67 and updating modules. 
[How do I generate CSRF tokens in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707119/how-do-i-generate-csrf-tokens-in-express)

Any help for a guy down on his luck? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `app.use(express.csrf());` is in the right order within your `app.configure()`. It needs to follow `express.session()`, `express.cookieParser()`, `app.bodyParser()`, `app.query()` -- and anything else that parses the submitted CSRF token into the `req` object.

Comment: In your example code you have an error: should be type="hidden" -- Note the end quote.

Comment: Fixed. I put it aside to work on some other stuff and updated to node .67, and somewhere in there it started working. Sorry I couldn't give a definitive answer, but thanks for your help.